# Angular template misplaced

Tags: angular

I'm trying to implement my app using the Angular framework. I'm currently working on communication with a server using WebSockets and everything was working fine until now.

I have created a component like so:

```
import { CountdownService, Countdown  } from './countdown.service';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import * as Rx from 'rxjs/Rx';

@Component({
moduleId: module.id,
selector: 'my-countdown',
templateUrl: 'countdown.component.html'
})
export class CountdownComponent {

itemName = 'Computer';

private countdown: Countdown;
constructor(private countdownService: CountdownService) {
    countdownService.countdowns.subscribe(time => {         
        this.countdown = time;
    });
}

}
```

All of the html is supposed to be shown at localhost:3000 and so it was before, but now the content of countdown.component.html has been moved to the URL:

```
http://localhost:3000/app/countdown.component.html
```

I really don't know what could be causing this. I also created this service since it was working properly:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, Subject } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import {WebSocketService } from './websocket.service';

const AUCTION_URL = 'ws://localhost:9999';

export interface Countdown {
days: number,
hours: number,
minutes: number,
seconds: number
}

@Injectable()
export class CountdownService {
public countdowns: Subject<Countdown>;

constructor(wsService: WebSocketService) {
    this.countdowns = <Subject<Countdown>>wsService
        .connect(AUCTION_URL)
        .map((response: MessageEvent): Countdown => {
            let data = JSON.parse(response.data);
            return {
                days: data.days,
                hours: data.hours,
                minutes: data.minutes,
                seconds: data.seconds
            }
        });
}
}
```

This is probably very simple to solve, but I'm new to Angular so any help is appreciated.

EDIT: Here is the main component:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
selector: 'my-app',
template: `
<h1>{{title}}</h1>
<my-countdown>Loading countdown ...</my-countdown>
<my-bidding>Loading bidding ...</my-bidding>
<my-bidlist>Loading bidlist ...</my-bidlist>
<my-popup></my-popup>
`
})
export class AppComponent  { 

title = 'Electronics Auction'; 

}
```

And my @NgModule:

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppComponent }  from './app.component';
import { BiddingComponent }  from './bidding.component';
import { CountdownComponent }  from './countdown.component';
import { BidlistComponent }  from './bidlist.component';
import { PopupComponent }  from './popup.component';

import { CountdownService }  from './countdown.service';
import { WebSocketService }  from './websocket.service';

@NgModule({
imports:      [ BrowserModule ],
declarations: [ 
  AppComponent,
  BiddingComponent,
  CountdownComponent,
  BidlistComponent,
  PopupComponent
],
providers: [CountdownService, WebSocketService],
bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: What happens when you visit http://localhost:3000 ? http://localhost:3000/app/countdown.component.html will be the location where the template is stored Angular will fetch that template when loading that component. Can you show me your main component that is being bootstrapped?

Comment: @JJB When i visit localhost:3000, the html from all of my components is shown, except for the html of countdown.component.html. I have now put the code of my main component in the post. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post your @ngModule? Are you seeing any console errors in the developer tools?

Comment: @JJB I have posted my ngModule. Yes, I am seeing errors, but I don't think they have anything to do with this. Here's the first one: 
core.umd.js:3491 EXCEPTION: Error in http://localhost:3000/app/countdown.component.html:3:20 caused by: Cannot read property 'days' of undefined

Comment: Can you check the network tab in the developer tools and look at the WebSocket connection and see what the data output is?

Comment: @JJB Sorry, I don't a lot of experience with that. Inside the network tab, i can see a 'webSocket.js'. Is that what I'm looking for? And how do I see the data output?

Comment: Open the network tab in Developer tools then press F5 to reload the page to make sure you capture all connections. Now you should see the name starting with ws:///  and the type WebSocket if you click on that you should see a right hand section display, it will have tabs Headers, Frames and Timing you need to click the Frames tab and you will see JSON data in rows.

Comment: @JJB There are 2 webSocket connections. 
This is the data from ws://localhost:3000/browser-sync/etc(it has a long name): https://gyazo.com/485d781ed6cd4400dade49e78ad3b977
And here's the one from ws://localhost:9999:  https://gyazo.com/194156d95a6208f50f234e20dd78d723

Comment: The browser-sync is for your development environment when code changes it will refresh the page etc so that's not the right one. The second connection is the right one. You will see that outputs the correct output. Can you add console.log(response); in your CountdownService so we can see what response outputs.

Comment: The other one is the server i made. It is supposed to send the remaining time of the countdown to the client.

Comment: Sorry, I really have to sleep now. I will check tomorrow. Thanks for your help so far!

Comment: @JJB This is what it is printing: 
MessageEvent {isTrusted: true, data: "{"days":0,"hours":0,"minutes":0,"seconds":44}", origin: "ws://localhost:9999", lastEventId: "", source: null…}

Comment: Can you post your countdown.component.html? Also I meant to say put the console.log in countdownService.countdowns.subscribe(time => { 
console.log("Time: ", time); If your using private countdown: Countdown; in your template really that shouldn't be a private variable. Shouldn't create a problem though.

Comment: @JJB Here is the countdown.component.html:
https://gyazo.com/394733c1cedd878a04c8ea47b9389d80

And this is what it prints:
Time:  Object {days: 0, hours: 0, minutes: 0, seconds: 58}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131086/discussion-between-jesper-and-j-j-b).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your component `CountdownComponent` variable `countdown` has no value set so when your template is rendered using `countdown.days` this will error because the `countdownService` subscription has not set the value of `countdown` yet, so it equals undefined.

You have two options to resolve this issue.

**Option 1 in your component:**

```
private countdown: Countdown = {days: null, hours: null, minutes: null, seconds: null};
```

---

**Option 2 in your template:**

```
{{countdown?.days}}
{{countdown?.hours}}
{{countdown?.minutes}}
{{countdown?.seconds}}
```